# Алгоритм вычитание "хоть одно"

Tags: javascript, jquery, алгоритм

Добро дамам и господам, i have массив

```
var results = {
'a': '1',
'b': '2'};
```

и мне нужно пробежаться по массиву так чтобы если у хоть одного ключа значение == 1 то кое-что сделать в jquery, также если хоть у одного ключа значение == 2 сделать кое-что в jquery = так на все цифирки от 1 до 5

То что у меня получилось:

```
for (var key in results) {
    if (results[key] == '1') {
        $('.avatar > img').attr('src', '/images/avatars/chief_1.svg') 
        break
    }
    if (results[key] == '2') {
        $('.avatar > img').attr('src', '/images/avatars/chief_2.svg') 
        break
    }
    if (results[key] == '3') {
        $('.avatar > img').attr('src', '/images/avatars/chief_3.svg') 
        break
    }
    if (results[key] == '4') {
        $('.avatar > img').attr('src', '/images/avatars/chief_4.svg') 
        break
    }
    if (results[key] == '5') {
        $('.avatar > img').attr('src', '/images/avatars/chief_5.svg') 
        break
    }
}
```

При `break` цикл заканчивает при первом же итерации, а

при `continue` изменение картинки подсчитывается только при второй итерации

Comment: используйте конструкцию switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать булевый массив, ключи которого — числа от 1 до 5, а значения — `true` или `false`, в зависимости от того, встречался ли уже такой ключ.

```js
let results = {
  'a': '1',
  'b': '2'
};

let isActionPerfomed = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
  isActionPerfomed[i] = false;
}

for (let key in results) {
  let value = results[key];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    if (value == i && !isActionPerfomed[i]) {
      console.log(`выполняем действие ${i}`);
      $('.avatar > img').attr('src', `/images/avatars/chief_${i}.svg`);
      isActionPerfomed[i] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за выделенное время,  но тут все равно меняется картинка при последней итерации `выполняем действие 4  выполняем действие 2` тут должно было поменяться картика на 2, а меняется на 4

Comment: Звучит очень странно. А чему равно `$('.avatar > img').attr('src')` после цикла?

Comment: самая минимальная - `chief_1.svg`

Comment: Должно менятся картинка на самую минимальную значение ключей в объекте)

Comment: Вам всегда нужно чтобы осталась самая минимальная? Может тогда просто взять минимум из значений вашего объекта (`minValue = Math.min(...Object.values(results))`), а потом один раз выполнить `$('.avatar > img').attr('src', "/images/avatars/chief_${minValue}.svg");`?

Comment: Это круто) об этом не подумал(, кстати а как взять минимальное значение с массива?

Comment: Я ведь вроде написал — `minValue = Math.min(...Object.values(results))`. Кстати, `results` это не [массив](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), а [объект](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: Понял спасибо вам большое, все сработало, а по поводу `minValue = Math.min(...Object.values(results))` не работал т.к я убрал ... подумав что это не должно быть, а как только обратно поставил заработо), можно мануалчик про эти точки "..." перед объектом

Comment: Это [оператор расширения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Для вашего объекта `results` (который `{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}`) результатом выполнения метода [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) будет массив `[1, 2]`. Без `...` получится `Math.min([1, 2])`, что не работает, а с `...` получится `Math.min(1, 2)`, что работает.

Comment: Понял, Большое спасибо вам)

Comment: @MelisZhoroev, пожалуйста :)